# How to Update Sqlite database using an api+job scheduler in android 21 and above?

Tags: android, service, android-sqlite, android-jobscheduler

I am trying to use Job Scheduler for updating the sqlite database. But the moment i start the app, it crashes and in logs it says it cant find a table. Could someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: you are probably not creating the database before querrying it. post relevant code

Comment: [link](https://github.com/pawankumarthakur/BadController) this is the updated repo with the code.